# Access Swift function for an object from Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, swift, function, class, objc-bridging-header

I'm trying to implement some Swift-framework into my Objective-C project. I have already set up all Bridge-Headers and also written @objc before functions and classes in a swift class. So it's required to do the following, but the example code is given in Swift:

```
barView.addBarBackground(startAngle: 90, endAngle: -270, radius: 100, width: 15)
```

I have to perform this code in Obj-c class for an object barView. I tried to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
[_barView.addBarBackground startAngle: 90 endAngle: -270 radius: 100 width: 15];
```

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

I have a IBOutlet connection:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet OGCircularBarView *barView;
```

So, there is an object named barView. I also have some Swift-class with the code:

```
import Cocoa

@objc public class OGCircularBarView: NSView, Sequence {
     //...
     @objc public func addBarBackground(startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, radius: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, color: NSColor) {
        //some code
     }
     //...
}
```

I need to perform that code (which is given in Swift) in an Objective-C class:

```
barView.addBarBackground(startAngle: 90, endAngle: -270, radius: 100, width: 15)
```

How can I rewrite it so that it works in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[_barView addBarBackgroundStartAngle: 90 endAngle: -270 radius: 100 width: 15];
```

The first problem is that you can't use dot syntax for methods; that's what the brackets are for: `[object message:withArguments:...]`

The second is that the Swift function name is a bit awkward for Obj-C translation. If you declare the swift function as follows:

```
func addBarBackgroundWithStartAngle(_ startAngle: Type, endAngle: Type...
```

... it would be translated to an easier-to-read:

```
[_barView addBarBackgroundWithStartAngle: endAngle: ...]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to add a background for an object named barView. And this background has some parameters as startAngle, endAngle, radius, etc. I must tell the function addBarBackground, what type of background do I need. See my edit

Comment: Y-yes. :-) That's what I'm answering. Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah! I've just change the function as you told and it works :)
Thank you!